# Как реализовать работу с потоком в cin

Tags: c++, поток-ввода, cin

Написал функцию, которая запрашивает ввод пользователя до тех пор, пока он не введёт число (если дробное, то преобразуется в целое с округлением к нулю). После этого поток очищается и возвращается первое введённое число.

Вопрос вот в чём: **возможно ли сделать так, чтобы выполнялось условие при вводе больше одного числа в поток?** Например, при вводе: 123 4 5

```
short safeInput() {

short val = 0;

while (!(std::cin >> val)) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cout << "Wrong input, only integers are expected!" << std::endl;
}

std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

return val;
```

}

Comment: "чтобы выполнялось условие". Какое условие? Что именно должно происходить "при вводе: 123 4 5"?

Comment: "преобразуется в целое с округлением к меньшему"? С округлением к нулю, наверное. Если ввести `-123.45`, то ваш код прочитает `-123`. А это не "округление к меньшему".

Comment: Если хотите  возвращать из функции первое введенное число, просто читайте только первое число без цикла, и возвращайте его ( непонятно в чем сложность)

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Сложность, как несложно догадаться, в обработке некорректного ввода. В этом и состоит задача. Отсюда и цикл.

Comment: @AnT, о каком некорректном  вводе речь, если вводятся только числа?

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Это откуда вы такое взяли? Пользователь может ввести что угодно )))

Comment: @AnT: Да, именно так. И спасибо, что поправили с отрицательными значениями.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan: Чтобы выполнялось условие в теле которого можно было бы отругать пользователя за некорректный ввод, как вариант :D
Ну а если пользователь введёт не число? Для этого и нужен цикл в теле которого, если это не число, сообщается о неверном вводе

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно поменять   `short val` на `double val` и возвращать из функции  `val < 0 ? --val : val;`.  И не важно после правильного ввода еще что введет пользователь...